# Kotlin: How to test that field is immutable

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I have a kotlin class as

```
class MyClass {
    val immutableField = "something"
}
```

I want to write a unit test to ensure that this field stays immutable, that if another developer (accidentally) changes this to `var` that some test will fail. How can I do this? (Now that I 
think about it I'm not sure how I would have done this in Java on a `final` field either)

This won't even compile so obviously this won't work:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@Test
fun checkFieldCantBeMuted() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
    myClass.immutableField = "something else"

    // assert field not updated
    assertThat(myClass.immutableField).isEqualTo("something")
}
```

*Now I know you might be saying, "Don't test the framework and don't test the language" but I'm not trying to assert that `val` results in immutability . I'm trying to assert that `immutableField` is a `val`.*

Comment: What's to stop somebody from changing the test as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use reflection to get the `KProperty` reference and then test its type:

```
MyClass::immutableField !is KMutableProperty<*>
```

Comment: Simpler: `MyClass::immutableField !is KMutableProperty<*>` :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyRomanov, I've edited my response. Totally forgot I could do that, thanks for the lesson! :)

Comment: Thx. FWIW AssertJ couldn't infer type so I couldn't do `assertThat(....).isTrue()`. Instead I had to do `assertThat(....).isEqualTo(true)`